# tracking non-standard gtm element

Tags: html, google-tag-manager

I'm looking to track a non-standard element, usually I'd track based on the class, but in this case the only unique element is 'ng-click', how do i activate this within Google Tag Manager and track this within Google Analytics?

Code:

```
<button class="btn-outline blue btn-block" ng-click="MC.changedEmail()">Submit<span class="loader" ng-hide></span></button>
```

and

```
<code><a href="#" class="btn-outline blue btn-block" ng-click="MC.signUp()">Go <span class="loader ng-hide"></span></a></code>
```

Comment: Hey Frank, Please update the code so we can understand the issue over here.

Comment: <code><a href="#" class="btn-outline blue btn-block" ng-click="MC.signUp()">Go <span class="loader ng-hide"></span></a></code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could track the clicked element via

1. the `{{Click Text}}` and fire your tag if `{{Click Text}}` equals "Go" or "Submit", or
2. you could create a new Auto-Event variable:

[image]

and fire your tag based on what's return through that variable.